# Is it safe to override __hash__ on a peewee.Model object?

Tags: python, orm, peewee

I recently noticed that my a bunch of peewee model objects that referred to the same data were not being recognized as equivalent, even though they contained the same data.

Is it safe to override __hash__ on these guys? It *appears* to work but I don't wan't this to come back and bite me unexpectedly in the future -- does hashing mess with anything like the internal state to record mapping that I should worry about?

```
class User(PowertailMeta):
    name = CharField(unique=True)
    password = CharField(null=False)
    balance = FloatField(default=10.0)
    cap = FloatField(default=60, constraints=[Check('cap >= 0')])
    is_admin = BooleanField(default=False)
    last_login = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    picture = CharField(default="porp")

    def __hash__(self):
       return hash(self.name) # since name is unique...
```

This passes trivial tests but I'm not sure what I might need to be looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`__hash__` has been recently added to `peewee.Model`, see https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/879. It's yet unreleased, but I assume it will be in 2.8.1.

The implementation is rather simple:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash((self.__class__, self._get_pk_value()))
```

(in https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/commit/4de894aeebf7245d4fb6c4f412c7a09a2c039d8a#diff-eb0556c6b1b9232ba053c4cea13ff075R4786)

So, it relies on the model class and your primary key. If you have other needs, I don't see any problem in overriding it. However, with your suggested solution, consider following:

```
class User(Model):
    name = CharField(unique=True)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)

class User(Model):
    label = CharField(unique=True)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.label)
```

These are two different models, even using different fields, but they would produce the same hash value.